# Three.js 2d heart is not displaying image right

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a web app that puts pictures into shapes and the other shapes work practically except for the heart. The image looks super distorted and since this is my first time using threejs I don't know how to fix it. Any help will be appriecated!

code for the heart function:

```
function handleHeart(img) {
        document.getElementById("divRight").innerHTML = ""
        let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        document.getElementById("divRight").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        renderer.setSize( document.getElementById("divRight").clientWidth, 600)

        let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, 1000 / 600, 0.1, 3000 );
        let scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( '235, 64, 52' );

        let x = 0;
        let y = 0;
        let heartShape = new THREE.Shape();
        heartShape.moveTo( x + 5, y + 5 );
        heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 5, y + 5, x + 4, y, x, y );
        heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x - 6, y, x - 6, y + 7,x - 6, y + 7 );
        heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x - 6, y + 11, x - 3, y + 15.4, x + 5, y + 19 );
        heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 12, y + 15.4, x + 16, y + 11, x + 16, y + 7 );
        heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 16, y + 7, x + 16, y, x + 10, y );
        heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 7, y, x + 5, y + 5, x + 5, y + 5 );

        const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( heartShape );

        //geometry.rotateX(0)
        //geometry.rotateY(0)
        geometry.rotateZ(110)
        geometry.translate( 5, 10, 10 )
        geometry.scale(30, 30, 0)

        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: img } );
        let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        //mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, 110 );
        //mesh.scale.y = 50;
        //mesh.scale.z = 50;
        //mesh.scale.x = 50;
        //img.repeat.set(mesh.Width / img.Width, mesh.Height / img.Height);

        mesh.position.set(0, 0, -1000);
        scene.add(mesh);





        renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGK3A.png)

Comment: You haven't assigned any UVs to your geometry, so it looks like only a small part of the heart gets accurate texture mapping, the rest is stretched out. [You should read about UVs and how they work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping).

Comment: Have a look at this forum post: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-use-uvs-in-shapebuffergeometry/20711/4

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at that!

Comment: I took a look at the link but that seems to be for shapeBufferGeometry and I don't really understand how to transfer that over to ShapeGeometry.

Comment: You can replace `new THREE.ShapeGeometry( heartShape )` with `new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( heartShape )` and then start updating the UV attributes as per that link.

Comment: Thank you so much it works like a charm now!